# Unilateral question closure

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

It appears that some users who are not moderators have the power to close questions by themselves. I'm not complaining; the closures are always reasonable. I'm just curious as to how this comes about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users with the gold badge for a particular tag can close (and reopen) questions in this tag instantly.

See [this post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/299332) for more information.